# How to reset Buffalo WHR-54g?

Tags: reset, buffalo-router

I can unsuccesfully accomplish [instructions](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/networks/7388-how-do-i-reset-buffalo-g54-air-station.html) such as:

> "The recessed reset button, simply
>   press and hold for a few seconds until
>   the DIAG LED illuminates to reset the
>   unit.". This implies that the unit
>   must be turned on first, press and
>   hold, and wait for the LED

Since my old settings required pubkey and password (not required with the defaults), I can see that I am unable to reset the box. The default should allow only some web interface, but my box still have SSH enabled, another thing to show the box is not reseted.

1. How does the web-interface thing work?
2. How to reset the buffalo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard Reset WHR-G54 by holding RESET down while powering it on. Hold 30 seconds, then remove power.

Comment: Holding down the RESET while waiting 30 seconds or only hold down the RESET a while when powering it on?

Comment: With the unit off hold the reset button in while you power up the router and continue to hold the reset button in for 30 seconds, then power it down again, Power up it should be reset.

Power up, power down, use the power cord to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Please, refer Buffalo's instructions: [here](http://www.buffalotech.com/support/downloads/).

> -1. How does the web-interface thing work?

The IP 192.168.1.1 worked for me but the Buffalo states the IP 192.168.11.1. Please, rtfm.

> -2. How to reset the buffalo?

Please, colsult the accepted reply: [here](https://superuser.com/questions/177551/how-to-reset-buffalo-whr-54g/177557#177557).